# paperclip resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have been working with the paperclip gem however, I can't seem to generate the size I want.

I have images with different sizes and I intend to resize them.

I need to have an image with a height of 175px and I don't care about the width.

I have tried working with this `175x175>`, `175>x175` and `175x175#`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try only passing a height and no width, which should be a valid ImageMagick option

```
x175
```

Instead of

```
175x175
```

Comment: these arguments are passed directly to imagemagick. You can experiment in command line and read imagemagick documentation to see the full scope of features you can use. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php?ImageMagick=v00hilk1a5jjfpuhg16c5nhtq0  once I started doing that I noticed that I can just use imagemagick for all my image conversion needs :)